# Guessing mnemonic phrase based on the first 2 public addresses

Tags: erc-20, metamask, wallets, mnemonic

Last hopeless attempt. I know that infinite amount of private keys can be generated from a mnemonic phrase and usually MetaMask, etc picks the first one from the list to use as the public address. Also if you create an additional account on the same MetaMask, it will generate an address which is the second in the list. I tried this in Ganache and I see it is true.
So would it be possible to guess the mnemonic phrase based on knowing the first 2 generated addresses?

I am asking this because I created a wallet on MEW which I used in Metamask as a primary account and then created an additional account without backup which has ERC20 tokens with high value locked now. Now I have lost my laptop and I only have the private key and password of Account 1 and the public address of account 2

Comment: if this were possible on a small scale, I would also recover the money stolen by professional scammers in crypto..and the scam trading platform ... regards, paul

Answer (score 0):

No, if this would be possible it would be a huge issue. In fact, you can't even know if two addresses were generated by the same mnemonic.

Answer (score 0):

If you created wallet account on same browser, and account1 is primary.
It can be possible you can get private key of account2 using mnemonic.