# Is it possible to guess the public addresses generated by MetaMask from the same seed?

Tags: metamask

If more than one of my public addresses (from same seed) are known, is it possible to guess other addresses generated from the same seed?

If I used 1 seed phrase to generate 10 addresses in MetaMask. If people know 1 or more of my public addresses, is it possible guess my other public addresses from the known ones?

I know this is a similar question to this one but just want to clarify.
[Guessing mnemonic phrase based on the first 2 public addresses](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/94212/68862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different private keys  generated from a single mnemonic phrase are in no way linked to eachother, so it's not possible to guess other private keys or addresses. This would only be possible if you have an *extended* public or private key, but it's generally not advised to give those to anyone.

If you're interested, I wrote an article about how the cryptography behind mnemonic phrases works, which you can find [here](https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-journey-from-mnemonic-phrase-to-address-6c5e86e11e14).